# Is there a limit on how many Realtime Database instances can you create with Blaze plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a limit on how many Realtime Database instances can you create with Blaze's plan on one Firebase project?

The pricing page just says "Multiple databases per project - yes".

Comment: I think the question would be more complete if you were to include why you're asking. Generally speaking, if you're creating a large number of Realtime Databases, you may be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: 2023-07-14**

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, there is a limit of 1,000 database instances per project. This is not currently mentioned in the official documentation but it be added shortly.

---

No, there is no limit on how many Realtime Database instances you can create. So they don't mention that because there isn't a fee for such operations. As a result, there is no threshold for doing that.

Comment: Hey Trypjon. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: there is actually limit of 1,000 database instances per project. We're working on adding that to the documentation.